# Shared folder not accessible from vagrant box after updating MacOS to Catalina (Stale file handle)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, macos-catalina

After updating MacOs to Cataline project hosted on Vagrant box stopped working. Shared directory was not accessible any more from box side:

```
vagrant@vagrant /var/www $ ls
ls: cannot access 'html': Stale file handle
html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to: Mac's prefs:

```
System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access
```

And add there file `/sbin/nfsd`

If you don't see that directory you may have to activate showing hidden files in Mac finder: open MacintoshHD in finder and press `Command+Shift+Dot`

If you don't even see MacintoshHD go to finder prefs and activate it in side bar options.